How to Use Both Internet and IPTV on Android TV via the Same Ethernet Connection?
I'm facing a challenge with my Android TV setup, and I’m hoping someone can help me out.
Here’s the situation:
My Android TV is connected to my ISP via an Ethernet cable to LAN Port 2 on the ONU (Optical Network Unit).
My ISP provides two VLAN profiles:
- VLAN 135 for internet.

Mode: Route
PPPoE
VLAN ID: 135
NAT Enabled

- VLAN 1900 for IPTV (supports IGMP).

Mode: Route
IPOE (DHCP)
VLAN ID: 1900
NAT Enabled

and there is Static Route for VLAN1900 Interface:
Destination       |subnet          |gateway    |Metric

138.138.138.0    |255.255.255.0   |11.0.0.9   |1

192.168.3.0      |255.255.255.0   |11.0.0.9   |1


The ONU only allows binding one VLAN profile per LAN port.

If I bind VLAN 1900, I can watch IPTV, but I lose internet access on
the TV (no OTT apps work).
If I bind VLAN 135, I have internet access but no IPTV service.

Additional details:

My ISP is developing its own IPTV app that can be installed directly
on Android TVs, eliminating the need for a separate set-top box.
I considered using Wi-Fi for internet access while keeping the
Ethernet cable for IPTV, but the TV automatically disables Wi-Fi when
it detects an Ethernet connection.

My Questions:

Is there a way to enable both internet and IPTV on my Android TV
using the same Ethernet connection?
If not, is there a workaround to make the TV use Wi-Fi for internet
while keeping the Ethernet connection active for IPTV?
Are there any specific networking solutions (like VLAN management
devices or switch configurations) that can help resolve this?

Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Can you clarify whether the ONU is set up as a router, or is it just a direct bridge to WAN?

@grawity I have Updated the details in the Question, thanks in advance

Normally a set-top box would handle it by being connected to a 'trunk' port with tagged VLANs. That is, the same LAN port would be "bound" to multiple VLANs at once, with all of them 'tagged' so that each packet also includes its VLAN ID. The STB (or a router, or a server) would internally have been set up with virtual interfaces corresponding to each tagged VLAN it wants to use.
Android cannot do that. Well, technically it could (since it's a built-in feature of the Linux kernel) but it's not available to Android apps, nor even handled by the Android OS at all – so it might be possible to set up tagged VLAN interfaces on a rooted device, but not through regular Android. Which means that if your ISP is moving towards using an app:

My ISP is developing its own IPTV app that can be installed directly on Android TVs, eliminating the need for a separate set-top box.

then the ISP should be providing a router configured for access to both VLANs so that the TV wouldn't need to care about it.
If they haven't done so, then you'll most likely need to set up your own router which could be in both VLANs, and (if your TV service uses multicast) which could support "IGMP proxy" and multicast forwarding for the TV VLAN.
